# R | Create a cross matrix

Tags: r

I don´t know how or where to start, but i hope someone can help. It´s the first time i´d use R like this, so even a keyword or a recommendation where to look it up would be helpful.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
  X = sample(c(1, 2, 3), 50, replace = TRUE),
  Y = sample(c(1, 2, 3), 50, replace = TRUE))
```

And I would like to get a cross table like this:

[image]

using

```
length(which(df$X ==  & df$Y == ))
```

I could calculate the data with R and fill it in my Excel-sheet but there has to be a better option.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this `base R` solution:

```
#Data
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
  X = sample(c(1, 2, 3), 50, replace = TRUE),
  Y = sample(c(1, 2, 3), 50, replace = TRUE))
#Code
addmargins(table(df$X,df$Y))
```

Output:

```
       1  2  3 Sum
  1    6  7  5  18
  2    4  6  9  19
  3    5  5  3  13
  Sum 15 18 17  50
```

You can also change the order of your variables like this:

```
#Code2
addmargins(table(df$Y,df$X))
```

Output:

```
       1  2  3 Sum
  1    6  4  5  15
  2    7  6  5  18
  3    5  9  3  17
  Sum 18 19 13  50
```

In order to export to MS Excel, you use this code:

```
library(xlsx)
#Transform to dataframe
d1 <- as.data.frame.matrix(addmargins(table(df$X,df$Y)))
#Export
write.xlsx(d1,file='myexample.xlsx','Sheet1')
```

Comment: Okay you got me, i reduced my example to a point where my intention isn´t clear anymore. Basically i need 1, 2, 3 to be replaced with more complex variables fulfilling conditions. But i guess you correctly answered my question so i will open a new one with a more detailed instruction.

Comment: I don't like the expression of `table(df$X, df$Y)` because it drops the columns names when forming a table. If you want to keep the columns names, you need to type `table(X = df$X, Y = df$Y)`, but it looks some tedious. I prefer using `table(df[c("X", "Y")])` or `xtabs( ~ X + Y, df)`, which keep the column names. Just a suggestion! Everybody has different aesthetic :)

Comment: @DarrenTsai Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the data have only two columns, just pass the `data.frame` object to `table`.

```
addmargins(table(df))
```

If the data include more than two columns, you can subset it's variable before passing to `table()`.

```
addmargins(table(df[c("X", "Y")]))
```

You can also pass a `formula` to `xtabs()`.

```
addmargins(xtabs( ~ X + Y, df))
```

All of above give

```
     Y
X      1  2  3 Sum
  1    5  6  3  14
  2    2  6  6  14
  3   13  4  5  22
  Sum 20 16 14  50
```

---

To export the table to an excel file, you can use `write.xlsx()` from `openxlsx`.

```
library(openxlsx)
tab <- addmargins(xtabs( ~ X + Y, df))
write.xlsx(tab, "foo.xlsx")
```

[image]